# HTTP UserAgent in MobileVLCKit for iOS

Tags: ios, vlc, libvlc

Is there any way to change default http headers (mainly User-Agent) with some options in MobileVLCKit for iOS?

I know I can pass options like this:

`[[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:@[option1, option2]];`

But where can I find the list of available options and can I change options after init?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See VLCLibrary's `- (void)setHumanReadableName:(NSString *)readableName withHTTPUserAgent:(NSString *)userAgent`, which should do exactly what you want.

For all the available options (which are not documented because they are explicitly not guaranteed to work or stay working across releases - use a proper libvlc/VLCKit API wherever you can!), see --longhelp --advanced on any VLC release.

Comment: Also could you please tell if it is possible to change/add any other HTTP Request headers? Thanks.

Comment: I tried this: `[[VLCLibrary sharedLibrary] setHumanReadableName:@"My Player" withHTTPUserAgent:@"My Payer 1.2.3"];` And User-Agent is still `VLC/3.0.0-git LibVLC/3.0.0-git` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, this may be a regression in the unstable code. Note that VLC 3.0 is far from being finished or stable. Will look into it. For the meantime, consider using the stable 2.2 branch.

Answer (score -1):

It should be e.g. "[[VLCLibrary sharedLibrary] setHumanReadableName:@"Mozilla" withHTTPUserAgent:@"Mozilla"]". But with 2.2.2 User-Agent doesn't change, User-Agent is still "VLC/2.2.2 LibVLC/2.2.2". Is this a bug or do I miss something?